# New line as Delimiter to make filters work

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I currently have VBA Code in excel that allows me to have several options selected from a data validation dropdown menu and returns them all in a single cell on a new line

```
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

Application.EnableEvents = True

On Error GoTo Exitsub

Select Case Target.Column
    Case 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
      If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
      Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
          If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
          Else
            If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
          Else:
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
          End If
        End If
      End If
End Select

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

For example:

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAhTH.png)

This is great and works how I would like it to but it does mean I can not filter single values as each cell shows as its own filter category.
How it behaves now:

[Filter box with many lines of text as categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HanYR.png)

How would I go about using a new line as a delimiter so that I can filter by individual categories?

How I'd Like it to behave:

[Filter Box with individual categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFOKX.png)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to use the built-in autofilter to do what you want: you will likely need to write your own filtering code.

Comment: I have an examble.xlsm with an implementation of something like that you want to do. I will post an screen copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: filtering cells with many lines]

> In column D are the data with many lines in each cell. In column E are the same data as in D, but every line of data is in different cell. In range D2:D9 you can set the filters. Each of theese cells have list dropdown with the values of column E. Each time happens a "change" in these cells the vba code filters the data.

```
'=======================THIS CODE IN Module1==========================
Option Explicit

Public existFilters As Boolean
Public excelRunsOk As Boolean

'CREATE THESE NAMED RANGES IN SHEET1 TO WORK THE EXAMPLE
'FILTER_LIST = sheet1!$E$13:$E$29
'SELECTED_FILTERS =sheet1!$D$2:$D$10   (workbook scope)

'this function is used in sheet cells and returns 1 (to show line) or 0 (to hide line)
'The cells in column F have formulas =checkF(D14;NOW()) We use the NOW() as second parameter to force excel refresh the cells value
Public Function checkF(r As Range, dummy As Variant) As Integer
   Dim selFilters As Range, C As Long, v As Variant, cv As Variant
   checkF = 0
   Call InitThisProgramm
   If existFilters = False Then Exit Function
   Set selFilters = Range("SELECTED_FILTERS")
   cv = Trim(r.Value)
   With selFilters
   For C = 1 To .CountLarge
      v = Trim(.Cells(C).Value)
      If v <> "" Then
         If cv = v Or cv Like "*" & v & "*" Then
            checkF = 1
            Exit Function
         End If
      End If
   Next
   End With
End Function

Public Function checkIfExistFilters() As Boolean
   Dim selFilters As Range, C As Long
   
   Set selFilters = Range("SELECTED_FILTERS")
   With selFilters
   For C = 1 To .CountLarge
      If Trim(.Cells(C).Value) <> "" Then
         checkIfExistFilters = True
         existFilters = checkIfExistFilters
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
   End With
   checkIfExistFilters = False
   existFilters = checkIfExistFilters
End Function


Public Sub No_Filters(ByRef r As Worksheet)
   With r
      If .FilterMode Then
         .ShowAllData
      End If
   End With
End Sub

Public Sub InitThisProgramm()
   If excelRunsOk Then Exit Sub
   
   'every time stop executing the code e.g. after a mistake we click the "Reset" (litle rectangle button)
   'all the variables initialized to default values by VB and we are miss the "state" of our programm
   'So, before executing code that depents on "state" e.g (has user selected filters?)
   'we must check if VB stoped (by checking the value of excelRunsOk) and if the value is false we have to
   'reinitialize our programm (). This is done by calling: call InitThisProgramm
   'Here we check if the user has select any filters. In real programms maybe here call many Subs or Functions
   'to do the state's Initiallization...
   
   Call checkIfExistFilters
   
   excelRunsOk = True
   '
End Sub




===========================this code is SHEET'S module CODE=========================

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("SELECTED_FILTERS")) Is Nothing Then
      Call checkIfExistFilters
      Call refreshFilter
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub refreshFilter()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Call No_Filters(Me)
   If existFilters = True Then
      Me.Range("$C$12:$F$29").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"
      
      'THE RANGE "$C$12:$F$29" FOR A REAL PROGRAMM MUST BE CALCULATED AND COME HERE WITH A DYNAMIC WAY
      'SO IF ADD MORE DATA, be adapted to include them
      'Field:=4, in a real programm the value 4 must be calculated   from it's relative position in filter columns...
      
   End If
End Sub


============================this code is Workbooks module code=========================
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call InitThisProgramm
End Sub
```